# "UPDATE OR ROLLBACK" produces a different result than "UPDATE" when used together with "INSERT OR REPLACE" trigger and unique constraint

Tags: sqlite

I'm using **sqlite3** version 3.8.8.3 and I'm wondering whether following problem leads to the expected result:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE ta (
 a integer(10) NOT NULL,
 id integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY );
INSERT INTO "ta" VALUES(1,1);
INSERT INTO "ta" VALUES(2,2);
INSERT INTO "ta" VALUES(3,3);
CREATE TABLE tb (
 a integer(10) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT c
    UNIQUE (a) );
INSERT INTO "tb" VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO "tb" VALUES(1);
CREATE TRIGGER t AFTER UPDATE ON ta
 FOR EACH ROW WHEN (old.a != new.a )
BEGIN INSERT OR REPLACE INTO tb(a) SELECT new.a; END;
COMMIT;

update or rollback ta set a=3;
```

--> Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: tb.a